# How can I use a variable as a field name in JSON stringify?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to be able to dynamically created a JSON object using a variable as the field name.

I've worked out how to set the field value from a variable using `$()` but it doesn't work for the field name.

```
    const body: string = JSON.stringify({
      '__metadata': {
        'type': listItemEntityTypeName
      },
      `${FIELD_NAME}`: `${FIELD_VALUE}`
    });
```

The error I get in VS Code is:

> [ts] Cannot invoke and expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '{ '__metadata': { 'type':string; }; }' has no compatible call signatures. [2349]
>   [ts] Property assignment expected. [1136]

I'm using typescript and react. I'm fairly new JavaScript so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: It should be `[FIELD_NAME]` not `\`${FIELD_NAME}\``

Comment: The term to look up here is "computed property names".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/how-to-use-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

Comment: Also, `${FIELD_VALUE}` (with the backticks around) can probably just be `FIELD_VALUE`, unless you want to convert any value into a string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anything that goes inside `JSON.stringify` should be a valid JSON Object

```
const body: string = JSON.stringify({
  '__metadata': {
    'type': listItemEntityTypeName
  },
  [FIELD_NAME]: `${FIELD_VALUE}`   // FIELD_VALUE should also be fine, if you dont want to convert it to string.
});
```

removing the string literal in the key can give you a valid JSON and hoepfully resolve the error

Comment: `FIELD_NAME` will just be `FIELD_NAME` as a key here. He has a variable of the same name.

Comment: Good catch @Jeto

Answer (score 1):

You can treat the object as an array.

```js
var FIELD_NAME = 'hello'
var FIELD_VALUE = 'world'

var obj = {
    '__metadata': {
        'type': 'aaaa'
    },
}

obj[FIELD_NAME] = FIELD_VALUE

console.log('obj', obj)
```